# Maximize the product of Hadamard matrix and a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices

Let $X$ be an $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix (i.e. entries are in $\{-1,1\}$ and rows are orthogonal). For my application, we can assume $n=2^k$.

Given a vector $\bf{w} \in R^n$, I want to find the $X^*$ that maximizes the minimum of the absolute value of all possible $X\bf{w}$.

$X^* = \arg\max$$(\min |X\textbf{w}|)$

Take $n=4$ for example,
$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1 \\
1&1&-1&-1 \\
1&-1&1&-1 \\
1&-1&-1&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&-1&-1 \\
1&-1&1&1 \\
1&1&-1&1 \\
1&1&1&-1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ are the only two possible matrices (for simplification, we can fix the first column to be 1 since we only care the absolute value). We can test which one reaches the maximum directly.

I have tried listing all matrices or convert it to an optimization problem, but it's not possible to solve for a larger n (ex. n=32).

Is this related to any known problem or is there any method to approach this problem? Or any approximation can also help.

Thanks in advance.

**[Edit] Add an example**

For the n=4 example, let's say $\textbf{w}=(-1.1,2.5,0.3,-4.3)$.

Then the first matrix gives $X\textbf{w}=(-8.2,1,5.4,-2.6)$ (min of abs is 1) and the second matrix gives $X\textbf{w}=(0.4,-7.6,-3.2,6)$ (min of abs is 0.4).

Therefore $X^*=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1 \\
1&1&-1&-1 \\
1&-1&1&-1 \\
1&-1&-1&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I don't get the definition of X*, it does not seem to make sense for a given fixed w.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I add an example to explain the definition. Hope it is now clearer.